# how to fix Autofac - require assembly qualification (my type. my assembly)

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow, autofac, workflow-engine

I did the dependency inversion with Autofac 3.5.with 3 separated projects (WorkFlowApp (MVC ASP.Net), WorkFlowAppBusiness, WorkFlowAppData) But I occurred " The type 'WorkFlowAppData.samplecontext.SampleContext, WorkFlowAppData' could not be found. It may require assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType, MyAssembly"." How can I solve?[image: Global.asax][image: AutofacConfig[![webconfig[![sampleContext]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dGUc.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEYQd.png)

[image: SampleContext]

[image: Project structure for WorkFlowData]

Comment: Your config is almost certainly wrong here. The fully qualified reference for the context is `WorkFlowAppData.SampleContexta.SampleContext` but your config only has `WorkFlowAppData.SampleContext`.

Comment: I wrongly upload the image. Actually, My project structure for WorkFlowAppData is updated in the question. Btw I already tried your way. but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not enough info. Need to see the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. I forgot to add WorkFlowApp.DataAccess reference to my WorkFlowApp. So Dependency Injection Issue. Thanks for your times.